# Entity Framework create database on removable drive

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Is there a good way to use EF to create a database from code first, where the database resides on a thumb drive?

Looking at some info from the [MS data developer center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674), it appears a wide range of options is available for the database connection. However, I can't quite figure out how to force a database connection to build a database on a removable or "thumb" drive, using Code First without an existing database.

By the way, I'm mainly coding in Visual Studio 2013 Express edition.

Comment: why not? its just another file. ef is only a ORM framework. your database engine has to decide where it is stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the connection string, use "AttachDbFilename=file.mdf"... "file.mdf" can include a path to a removable drive. For example, "AttachDbFilename=E:\file.mdf;"